Facebook itself was spamming me with never ending page posts
After at least a month receiving those never ending posts of Page Ads, and trying to block them, which never seemed to work, I spent 4 straight days clicking on every post they sent me using the REPORT POST option, which also includes a blocking button 1/2 way through the process.  I chose the BULLYING, HARASSMENT or ABUSE option then the BULLYING, HARASSMENT option then the ME option, continued through the rest of the form and be sure to wait for the result to post before clicking on DONE.   I didn't count but I must have done this to a few hundred Posts, and suddenly today they stopped coming.  I don't know if this is a temporary break but it feels good anyhow.

I don't see a question in there.
